# Can we say that a database is a webservice that works with data on filesystem?

Tags: database

These days, i made a webservice, that extracts data from files, sort, search etc.. and retrive data to the request sender.

Then, i noticed that it was like how a database works, it take a "query" which is equal to a string with keywords in it and then filter data on files, based on the request parameters.

Can we say that a database is a webservice that works with data on filesystem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Usually not.

It is rare that communication with a database is done over HTTP, especially when a database uses SQL.

Web services are very much a subset of all services.